# What is the procedure for manually relocating the Exchange server data for SBS2008?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008

I've used the Windows SBS Console and it's "Move Exchange Server Data" wizard to move my Exchange server data from the C drive to the D drive.

The wizard didn't allow me to choose where on the D drive I wanted the Exchange server data to be placed though.

What is the procedure for manually relocating the Exchange server data for SBS2008?

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb for SBS is don't do anything outside of an SBS wizard that you can do within an SBS wizard. While it may not be appealing to whatever structure you'd like on your drive, I'd heavily advise against ever doing anything outside of the SBS wizards. There are so many scripts used for everything that you're very likely to break some component of SBS by doing even simple things.

Comment: that isn't really what he wants. yes he shouldn't do it 'manually', but he really wants the original problem fixed...

Comment: @Joshua - There's no problem. Nothing is broken. It just won't let him put it in the path he wants. That's not a good reason to leave the SBS wizards.

Comment: "It just won't let him put it in the path he wants. " ->> that is broken... I'm not suggesting he leaves the wizard, your answer is useless in terms of help... Maybe you could mention what/where these other scripts are, or how to fix this? Personally I'm thinking he missed the browse button but maybe it is greyed out or something.

Comment: @Joshua - I mean no offense, but it doesn't seem like you know how Small Business Server works at all. My answer is not the answer he wants to hear, but it's the correct thing to do. It is never a good idea to do something that the manufacturer doesn't support and Microsoft does not support doing anything in SBS outside of wizards that can be done within wizards, no matter what reason you may have for wanting to do so. He did not simply miss a button. SBS is very picky in what it allows you to within the wizards and changing the path is not something it allows.

Comment: WTF you talking about. Screenshot below proves you can change the path. Have you actually tried to do this yourself?

Comment: @Joshua - That's not an SBS wizard screenshot. Like I said, you don't seem to know a whole lot about Small Business Server. I'm not meaning to insult you, just pointing out that you're speaking outside of your expertise.

Comment: @JasonBerg let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1113/discussion-between-joshua-dalton-and-jason-berg)

Answer (score -1):

Use exchange server console. Drill down to the databases, then click on right to move. If you click browse it should let you pick where you want it. For example F:\some\random\directory\

[image: SBS2008 exchange move directory]